# Where to write testcases for mobile apps

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests

I am a tester, but putting my hands on in Android app development and have developed a EdTech app "[Class eLearn Mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.udayrepo.classelearn)"

As of now, i am manually testing the application and pushing the updates to production.

But now i want to write automated cases in the same development project and implement CI/CD or DevOps. How can we do that? I know in Maven projects, we can have a separate test folder, where we can write functional tests. How can i do the same with Android apps?

Your inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: *I know in Maven projects, we can have a separate test folder, where we can write functional tests. How can i do the same with Android apps* open android studio, open the test or androidTest folder. They are in app/src

Comment: @TimCastelijns, Once i write my testcases there, while building the apk or bundle, can i exclude these testcases, so the app only take the size of the source code?

Comment: of course, that is default behavior

Comment: @TimCastelijns, thanks for your quick response. U mean, it only takes the source code files and excludes files from androidTest folder? How to run only functional testcases from Android Studio?

Comment: You can right click on your test class and ```Run "YourTestClassTest"``` also you can do it by command line ```./gradlew test{Flavour}{Debug|Release}UnitTest``` for unit testing and ```./gradlew connected{Flavour}{Debug|Release}AndroidTest``` for instrumental tests

Comment: seriously just read the docs

Comment: Just to give a sample of the aforementioned cases ```./gradlew connectedProductionDebugAndroidTest``` and ```./gradlew testDevelomentReleaseUnitTest```